# What is the equivalent of hive query for the below sql

Tags: oracle, hive

What is the equivalent query in hive for

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate,'iw')-1)
```

Comment: Someone who is not familiar with Oracle has no idea what your talking about. At least you should specify what input you have and what output you expect and why.

Comment: IN Oracle SQL we have function (iw) first day of the week,Is there any function in hive which will return the first day of the week. Like here i am passing sysdate as input parameter and out is also date return with "DD-MM-YY".

Answer (score 0):

You could go about this at least two ways:

Either implement your own function in hive using the UDF capability

OR

Use a manipulation of a case statement and modulus of the date:

In rough code this would be something like:

```
select pmod(datediff(date_column,'2012-01-02'),7)+1 as day_of_week, case when day_of_week = 1 then date_column else when day_of_week = 2 then date_add(date_column,-1)
```

etc.